# 26% of adults wear contact lenses and two are selected randomly. Given that at least 1 of these adults wears lenses...

Tags: probability

> $26\%$ of adults wear contact lenses and two are selected randomly. Given that at least $1$ of these adults wears lenses, what is the probability that both wear contact lenses?

So I figured 
$$P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A) P(B|A) = 0.26 \times 0.26 = P(0.26) P(B|A).$$
So I divide $0.0676$ by $0.26$ and get $0.26$. I'm not sure that I've done this right I've been looking for answers online and I've been stuck for an hour. Help is much needed. Thanks.

---

I also tried adding the sums of the possibilities. Probability of $A$ but not $B$. So $0.26 \times 0.76$ then (Prob of not $A$ but $B$) $+ 0.76 \times 0.26$ which gave me $\longrightarrow 0.1924 + 0.1924 = 0.3848$. Then divide $0.0676$ by $0.3848$? Sorry I don't know how to make proper math symbols.

Comment: Continue to include your thoughts and efforts in future posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's so tempting to answer $0.26$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

26% of adults wear contact lenses and two are selected randomly. Given that at least 1 of these adults wears lenses

Let $A = \{\text{At least 1 wears lenses}\}$, $B = \{\text{2 wear lenses}\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
P(B|A) &= \frac{P(AB)}{P(A)}\\ 
&= \frac{P(B)}{P(\text{One of two wears})+P(\text{Two of two wear})} \\
&= \frac{.26(.26)}{\binom{2}{1}(.26)(1-.26)+\binom{2}{2}(.26)^2(1-.26)^0}\\
&= 0.1494253
\end{align*}
since $A\cap B =B$.

You can also calculate as follows
\begin{align*}
P(B|A) &= \frac{P(AB)}{P(A)}\\ 
&= \frac{P(B)}{1-P(\bar A)} \\
&=\frac{.26(.26)}{1-\binom{2}{0}(.26)^0(1-.26)^2}\\
&=0.1494253.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why do you add the sum of the probability of Two of Two wear? Is it just because you have to take every circumstance then divide?

Comment: $P(A)$  means the probability of **at least** one wears lenses. Then either one wears lenses or two wear lenses. So $P(A)$ is equal to the sum of the probability that exactly one wears or exactly two wears, since these events are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @TaylorKern No problem. Glad to help.